# Can't use Phreeqc with my python script to model chemical speciation

Tags: python

I am trying to run a script on python 3, combined with the phreeqpy package but I am getting mad because I tried everything but it keeps giving error.
The script:

```py
import pandas as pd
from phreeqpy.iphreeqc import IPhreeqc

def run_phreeqc(database_path, input_string):
    phreeqc = IPhreeqc()
    phreeqc.load_database(database_path)
    phreeqc.run_string(input_string)
    return phreeqc.get_selected_output()

def generate_input_string(samples_data):
    input_string = "TITLE Example\n"

    for i, sample_data in enumerate(samples_data, start=1):
        input_string += f"SOLUTION {i}\n"
        input_string += f"temp {sample_data['T']}\n"
        input_string += f"pH {sample_data['pH']}\n"
        input_string += f"pe {sample_data['Eh']}\n"  # Add Eh value
        input_string += "units mg/L\n"

        for element, concentration in sample_data["elements"].items():
            # Convert trace elements to mg/L
            if element in sample_data["trace_elements"]:
                concentration /= 1000
            input_string += f"{element} {concentration}\n"

        input_string += "\n"

    input_string += """
        SELECTED_OUTPUT
        -reset false
        -totals REE
        EQUILIBRIUM_PHASES 1
        REE_speciation
    """

    return input_string

def main():
    database_path = "C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/PythonCourse/Lib/site-packages/phreeqpy/iphreeqc/phreeqc3/IPhreeqc-3.7.3.dll"
    data_file = "C:/Users/alessandro/Desktop/Data.csv"

    # Read the data from the CSV file
    data = pd.read_csv(data_file, encoding='latin-1')

    samples_data = []

    # Process each sample in the dataset
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        sample_data = {
            "T": row["T"],
            "pH": row["pH"],
            "Eh": row["Eh"],
            "elements": {
                "DOC": row["DOC (mg/L)"],
                "Na": row["Na"],
                "Mg": row["Mg"],
                "K": row["K"],
                "Ca": row["Ca"],
                "Al": row["Al"],
                "Mn": row["Mn"],
                "Fe": row["Fe"],
                "Ba": row["Ba"],
                "Pb": row["Pb"],
                "Sc": row["Sc"],
                "La": row["La"],
                "Ce": row["Ce"],
                "Pr": row["Pr"],
                "Nd": row["Nd"],
                "Sm": row["Sm"],
                "Eu": row["Eu"],
                "Gd": row["Gd"],
                "Tb": row["Tb"],
                "Dy": row["Dy"],
                "Y": row["Y"],
                "Ho": row["Ho"],
                "Er": row["Er"],
                "Tm": row["Tm"],
                "Yb": row["Yb"],
                "Lu": row["Lu"],
                "Zr": row["Zr"],
            },
            "trace_elements": {
                "Al", "Mn", "Fe", "Cu", "Ba", "Pb", "Sc", "La", "Ce", "Pr", "Nd", "Sm", "Eu", "Gd", "Tb", "Dy", "Y", "Ho", "Er", "Tm", "Yb", "Lu", "Zr"
            }
        }
        samples_data.append(sample_data)

    input_string = generate_input_string(samples_data)
    result = run_phreeqc(database_path, input_string)

    # Save the results in a CSV file
    results_df = pd.DataFrame(result)
    results_df.to_csv("ree_speciation_results.csv", index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects\PythonCourse\Speciation.py", line 2, in <module>     
from phreeqpy.iphreeqc import IPhreeqc ImportError: 
cannot import name 'IPhreeqc' from 'phreeqpy.iphreeqc'
(C:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects\PythonCourse\Lib\site-packages\phreeqpy\iphreeqc\__init__.py)
```

phreeqpy is installed correctly and works with another easier script by using "import phreeqpy.iphreeqc.phreeqc_dll as phreeqc_mod"

Could you help me? Many thanks all!

I expected to run a script with python combined with phreeqc to get the chemical speciation for a certain solution.

Comment: Please move those hashtags from the title to the tags below, where they belong. That said, if it works with a different script, what is the difference between the two? Also, is all that code necessary, i.e. is it a [mcve]? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: From skimming [the documentation](https://www.phreeqpy.com/examples/index.html), and reading your error message, it seems the problem is that `IPhreeqc` is not defined within the namespace of `phreeqpy.iphreeqc`. The example given in the documentation shows loading a particular module file based on dll or com mode, and then getting `IPhreeqc` from that package.  What you probably want is something like `from phreeqpy.iphreeqc.phreeqc_dll import IPhreeqc`